# A high-voltage logic part in PSpice

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, pspice

I'm trying to build the following part of a circuit:

[image]

I'm wondering what the part is that has "HI" written on it; I couldn't find it in any PSpice guide.

Comment: Looks like a net label, indicating that those pins are tied high.

Comment: $d_lo and $d_hi are the ones I found with the packages I had

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'HI' would probably indicate a high voltage level, or logic-level high, also known as Vcc, usually 1.8 V, 3.3 V or 5 V.

It's up to the designer to determine what value 'HI' is, and it is probably located somewhere else on the schematic.

Also that is a port, it indicates that the two nets are tied together in the schematic, without them being wired together directly (thus making a rats nest of wires).

Comment: Do you know perhaps how can I place this part and use it? (and set the wanted voltage level?)